# Inserting binary data into BLOB columns

Tags: php, sqlite, laravel, blob, laravel-5

How do I insert binary data into a column of type `BLOB` of a SQLite database in Laravel?

Comment: if you're happy with my answer below, you can accept it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If column in your table is BLOB type, e.g. you created it in migration like this:

```php
Schema::table('images', function($table) {
    $table->binary('data');
})
```

Then you should be able to insert binary data by using regular `insert()` method:

```php
DB::table('images')->insert([
    'data' => $binaryFile   
]);
```

Or like this:

```php
DB::table('test')->insert([
    'data' => DB::raw("LOAD_FILE('/path/to/file')")
]);
```

Comment: Thank you. It tried several try , but eventually was implemented in x'1234567'.
http://sqlite.1065341.n5.nabble.com/Inserting-BLOB-values-td3611.html